# How to copy html and plain text to clipboard in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, clipboard

I try to copy a HTML and plain text set to clipboard, so that each editor can choose if he wants to paste `text/html` or `text/plain`.

I am using `navigator.clipboard.write()` (the **[async clipboard api](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#async-clipboard-api)**).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is quite simple, you can pass multiple blobs to one `ClipboardItem`:

```js
const blob = new Blob([
    '<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">goto stack</a>'
], { type: "text/html" });
const blobPlain = new Blob(['goto stack'], { type: "text/plain" });

navigator.clipboard.write([
    new ClipboardItem({
        [blob.type]: blob,
        [blobPlain.type]: blobPlain
    },),
])
```

[Be aware this will not work in every browser (right now).](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardItem/ClipboardItem)